# Printing Email Messages (via Visualforce)

Tags: apex, visualforce, servicecloud, emailmessage, printable

How can I print email messages via Visualforce?

Comment: Liam -- great post but rework it as a question, and then create an answer. Two days later, you can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the solution:

**Controller Class:**

```
public class EmailMessageController {
    public EmailMessage email {get; set;} // Holds the email message record

    public EmailMessageController() {
        // Get the emailMessageId from the URL parameter
        String messageId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('emailMessageId');

        // Query the EmailMessage record based on the passed ID, including additional fields
        if(messageId != null) {
            email = [SELECT Id, FromAddress, MessageDate, ToAddress, CcAddress, Subject, HTMLBody 
                     FROM EmailMessage WHERE Id = :messageId LIMIT 1];
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller Test Class:**

```
@isTest
private class EmailMessageControllerTest {

    // Method to set up test data
    static testMethod void setup() {
        // Insert a test EmailMessage record
        EmailMessage testEmail = new EmailMessage(
            FromAddress='test@example.com',
            ToAddress='receiver@example.com',
            Subject='Test Email',
            HTMLBody='This is a test email body',
            MessageDate=DateTime.now()
        );

        insert testEmail;
    }

    // Test the constructor behavior with a valid emailMessageId
    static testMethod void testValidEmailMessageId() {
        // Set up test data
        setup();

        // Mock current page and set emailMessageId parameter
        Test.setCurrentPage(Page.EmailMessagePreview); // replace with actual Visualforce page name associated with the controller
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('emailMessageId', [SELECT Id FROM EmailMessage LIMIT 1].Id);

        // Instantiate the controller
        EmailMessageController controller = new EmailMessageController();

        // Perform assertions to ensure the controller loaded the EmailMessage correctly
        System.assertNotEquals(null, controller.email, 'The email property should not be null');
        System.assertEquals('test@example.com', controller.email.FromAddress, 'The FromAddress should match the test data');
    }

    // Test the constructor behavior with an invalid or null emailMessageId
    static testMethod void testInvalidEmailMessageId() {
        // Mock current page without setting an emailMessageId parameter
        Test.setCurrentPage(Page.EmailMessagePreview);

        // Instantiate the controller
        EmailMessageController controller = new EmailMessageController();

        // Perform assertions to ensure the controller behaves correctly when no ID is passed
        System.assertEquals(null, controller.email, 'The email property should be null when an invalid ID is passed');
    }

}
```

**Visualforce Page:**

```
<apex:page controller="EmailMessageController">
    <style>
        /* General style for the page */
        #buttonContainer {
            text-align: left; /* Align the print button to the left */
            margin-bottom: 10px; /* Spacing between button and content */
        }
        #printButton {
            padding: 5px 10px; /* Sizing for print button */
        }

        /* Style adjustments for print media */
        @media print {
            body * {
                visibility: visible !important; /* Show everything in the body when printing */
            }
            #printButton, #buttonContainer {
                display: none; /* Hide print button and its container when printing */
            }
            #printableArea {
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
            }

            /* @page directive for print layout */
            @page {
                size: auto;
                margin: 5mm;  /* Margin on every side of the page */
            }
        }

        /* Style for the header section */
        #header {
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-bottom: 20px; /* Add margin to separate header and content */
        }
    </style>

    <!-- Add script to disable right-click, intercept Ctrl+P, and automatically invoke print dialog -->
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            if (!{!ISNULL(email)}) { // Checks if email is not null
                window.print(); // Automatically invoke print dialog
            }
        });

        document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); // Disable right-click menu on the entire document
            alert("Right-click is disabled. Please use the 'Print' button in the upper left corner.");
        }, false);

        document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
            // Intercept Ctrl+P and Command+P (for MacOS)
            if ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) && e.keyCode == 80) {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert("Keyboard Shortcut for printing is disabled. Please use the 'Print' button in the upper left corner.");
            }
        }, false);
    </script>

    <!-- Container for the print button -->
    <div id="buttonContainer">
        <button id="printButton" onclick="window.print();">Print</button>
    </div>

    <!-- Header section -->
    <div id="header">
        <!-- Email details -->
        <div>
            <strong>From:</strong> {!email.FromAddress}<br/>
            <strong>Sent Date:</strong> {!email.MessageDate}<br/>
            <strong>To:</strong> {!email.ToAddress}<br/>
            <strong>CC:</strong> {!email.CcAddress}<br/>
            <strong>Subject:</strong> {!email.Subject}<br/><br/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Main content section -->
    <div id="printableArea" style="margin-top: 100px;"> <!-- Adjust margin-top as needed -->
        <!-- HTMLBody of the EmailMessage -->
        <apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!email.HTMLBody}" rendered="{!email != null}"/>
    </div>

    <apex:outputText value="No Email Message found or you did not provide an emailMessageId." rendered="{!email == null}"/>
</apex:page>
```

I have designed the page to look the same as if you were printing an email via Outlook. When the page is called the print dialogue box automatically appears for the user to click print. Should the user click 'Cancel', there is another Print button on the page so they can initiate the print window again. You will also see in the VF page code that I have blocked some standard browser settings, like Right-Click and the ability to use Ctrl+P (Cmd-P for mac users) as this will then want to print the entire screen screen, including the Salesforce UI.

Finally, your probably wondering how to call this Visualforce page from an email message record. I simply used a flow with the custom navigation redirect component that automatically redirects the user to a specified URL (in this instance the Visualforce page with the 'emailmessageId' passed as a parameter in the URL). For those wanting to use this method, you can find the custom app here (https://unofficialsf.com/fsc-navigation-button/).